# cannot upload image to django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, httpie

I need to upload an image to django server with django rest framework. I tried to post the image using httpie and I am getting this error.

http 400 no image was submitted.

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from myapp.models import *


class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True)


    class Meta:
        model = MyPhoto
        fields = ('id', 'image')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class MyPhoto(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', max_length=254)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from myapp.models import *
from myapp.serializers import PhotoSerializer
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser


class PhotoList(APIView):

    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        photo = MyPhoto.objects.all()

        serializer = PhotoSerializer(photo, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

       serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have set`MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`.

Comment: did you reciving image in the request.POST

Comment: The photo is not uploaded to the folder. How to check whether the data is in request.POST?

Comment: in the post method put pdb , 
def post(self, request, format=None):
      import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
 then in try to post the image then the terminal print the request.data

Comment: try `self.request.FILES['image']`

Comment: When I print request.data I am getting QueryDict:{'data': InMemoryUploadedFIle: myfilename

Comment: @vinaykumar when I tried that , I am getting the following error. invalid data . Expected a dictionary, but got inmemeoryuploadedfile

Comment: @VivinKarthik Just update post method it will work. 
`serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.data, files=request.FILES)`

please look into file parser http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

Comment: @vinaykumar I am getting the following error. __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument files http 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. this might help you to resolve your issue.

## views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from myapp.models import *
from myapp.serializers import PhotoSerializer

class PhotoList(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    queryset = MyPhoto.objects.all()
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from myapp.views import PhotoList
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'photo', PhotoList, 'photo')

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Just use url in browser `http://localhost:8000/photo/`.

Comment: Can I post an Image with this code? When I am trying Attribute error:RegexUrlPattern attribute object has no attribute _call back

Comment: I am posting the image using httpie in command prompt.
http -f post <url> image@url

Comment: Got it correct. It was a syntax error in httpie. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure. What about uploading multiple images? how to do that? How could I choose each and store it in database?

Comment: @VivinKarthik uploading images is heavy duty work. I'll suggest one api call for one image will be good.

Comment: Oh I get it. But in my app a user has to upload multiple photos during registration. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Ok.. you can upload multiple image like [this](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and just map your image upload api in javascript. It will work.